# Problema con consulta a tabla apuntada 2 veces desde otra tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql

Tengo un problema con una consulta. Estoy trabajando en Oracle y tengo una tabla que apunta por medio de 2 atributos (**APROBADOR** y **EJECUTOR**) hacia otra tabla a su primary key (**RUT**):

[image: Tablas PROGRAMAS y USUARIOS en Oracle]

Me gustaría retornar por medio de la consulta el nombre del Aprobador y el Ejecutor

[image: Resultado esperado de consulta]

¿Es esto posible con una simple consulta?

Probablemente la respuesta sea sencilla pero por mas que lo intento no me da resultado :(

Gracias de antemano por el tiempo y sus respuestas

Comment: que intentaste? si se puede, en el from una misma tabla puede aparecer varias veces ;)

Comment: jaja buena crack, jamás se me ocurrió hacer eso !!! gracias